# Arrays.sort magic number

Tags: java, sorting

From `Arrays.sort` source code:

```
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    sort1(a, 0, a.length);
}
```

And then :

```
private static void sort1(int x[], int off, int len) {
    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (len < 7) {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
    if (len > 7) {
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Where this magic number 7 come from and why?

[Link to the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort1%28int%5B%5D,int,int%29)

Comment: Because different sort algorithms work better on different array sizes.

Comment: 7 came from benchmarking to find out which algorithms work better on arrays of different sizes.

Comment: Probably [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6650182/1163607).

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Java sort algorithm switches from mergesort to quicksort when the list gets small enough. The source references a text, you might want to check there if you're curious.